# Query Memory available in zVM

Tags: zos

Can a user of a zVM virtual machine query the allocated memory size (VM RAM size?), from USS?

I've had some success getting the CP info using `oeconsol "d m=cpu"`.

While some [sources](http://idcp.marist.edu/pdfs/ztidbitz/MVS%20CONSOLE%20COMMANDS.pdf) suggest that the equivalent command for memory should be `oeconsol "d m=stor"`, I get nothing from it, nor the superset command `oeconsol "d m"`.